# Pasar valores en viceversa con Javascript o jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Hola estoy trabjando con mathquill, lo que sucede es que tengo este formato de expresion

```
     sqrt[]{}
```

que puede ser

```
     sqrt[3]{4+5-8}
```

o cualquier numero dentro de los corchetes y llaves, lo que hice fue modificar el template de la api de la raiz que es:

```
   _.textTemplate = ['sqrt[',']{','}'];
```

por este

```
    _.textTemplate = ['(',')^(1/',')'];
```

por lo que el resultado es:

```
    (3)^(1/4+5-8)
```

El problema es que los valores van al reves, 
y deberian de mostrarse asi:

```
    (4+5-8)^(1/3)
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Necesito de vuestra ayuda por favor

Comment: la modificación del template, la hiciste sobreescribiendo el método `LatexCmds.nthroot` o editaste la fuente en duro en la librería?

Comment: edite el template, borre el anterior template y puse este  _.textTemplate = ['(',')^(1/',')'];

Comment: Entiendo que editaste el template pero donde? Te hiciste una clase nthroot nueva?

Comment: No, lo edite directamente de la misma nthroot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolvi el problema con la funcion `_.text`,
la modifique para que retornara el template con los valores en viceversa

```
 _.text = function(){ return  '('+this.ends[R].text()+')'+'^(1/'+this.ends[L].text()+')'; };
```

al final el código quedo así:

```
    var NthRoot =
LatexCmds.nthroot = P(SquareRoot, function(_, super_)
{
  _.htmlTemplate =
      '<sup class="mq-nthroot mq-non-leaf" style="margin-top:1%">&0</sup>'
    + '<span class="mq-scaled">'
    +   '<span class="mq-sqrt-prefix mq-scaled">&radic;</span>'
    +   '<span class="mq-sqrt-stem mq-non-leaf">&1</span>'
    + '</span>'
  ;


 _.text = function(){ return  '('+this.ends[R].text()+')'+'^(1/'+this.ends[L].text()+')'; };

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Supongamos entonces que tomaste `nthroot`

```
var NthRoot =
LatexCmds.nthroot = P(SquareRoot, function(_, super_) {
  _.htmlTemplate =
      '<sup class="mq-nthroot mq-non-leaf">&0</sup>'
    + '<span class="mq-scaled">'
    +   '<span class="mq-sqrt-prefix mq-scaled">&radic;</span>'
    +   '<span class="mq-sqrt-stem mq-non-leaf">&1</span>'
    + '</span>'
  ;
  _.textTemplate = ['sqrt[', '](', ')'];
  _.latex = function() {
    return '\\sqrt['+this.ends[L].latex()+']{'+this.ends[R].latex()+'}';
  };
});
```

Y cambiaste

```
 _.textTemplate = ['sqrt[', '](', ')'];
```

Por

```
 _.textTemplate = ['(',')^(1/',')'];
```

Para lo que quieres hacer, si te fijas el comando que llega a Latex:

```
return '\\sqrt['+this.ends[L].latex()+']{'+this.ends[R].latex()+'}';
```

Sigue diciendo : transforma esto en `\\sqrt[param izquierdo]{param derecho}`

Tenías que cambiar esa parte para que fuera

```
return '\\sqrt['+this.ends[R].latex()+']{'+this.ends[L].latex()+'}';
```

Comment: Ya había hecho eso pero no obtuve ningun resultado hasta borre el retiro,Ati te funcionó?

Comment: No, nunca he usado mathquills, ni siquiera Latex. Sólo aventuré una respuesta mitando el [código fuente](https://github.com/mathquill/mathquill/blob/6b03f498a47b9f275558facc88d714098e5d416b/src/commands/math/commands.js#L507)

Comment: hola de nuevo descubri que si pones el signo de + y quitas la coma el valor pasa al siguiente cuadro de texto, pero el otro valor no se como regresarlo al primer cuadro

Comment: _.textTemplate = ['('+')^(1/',')'];